# Do the math sum of a text variable? (E.g 5865/100 )

Tags: php, math, variables, eval

I have a variable that is...

`$whatever = "5865/100";`

This is a text variable.

I want it to calculate 5865/100 , so that I can add it to other numbers and do a calculation.

Number_format doesn't work, as it just returns "5,865". Whereas I want it to return 58.65

I could do...

```
$explode=explode("/",$whatever);
if(count($explode)=="2") {
    $whatever = $explode[0]/$explode[1];
}
```

But it seems rather messy. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: texxxt variable?? is that's what we call variables holding strings now? how phpunky.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Evaluate as PHP expression, but first check if it contains only digits and operators and space, and suppress any errors.

```
if (preg_match('/^[\d\+\-\/\*\s]+$/', $s)) {
  @eval('$result = ' . $s . ';');
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the ; after eval and inside it, too.

Comment: Let's have a code competition to see who can write dangerous code consisting of only digits and mathematical operators.  Is it possible?

Comment: using $result inside a double quoted (") string will cause PHP to try and replace  the $result variable before evaluating the expression.

Comment: In order to make PHP evaluate the expression you'd have to write a valid PHP expression, but you can have only integer operands, and therefore all operators are mathematical. So if it is a valid expression, it will evaluate to an integer with no side effects.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [eval](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function to evaluate a string as code.  However, you have to be careful as to where this code comes from because it will execute anything passed to it, not just simple math.  If you knew your string contained a mathematical formula, you could do the following

```
$answer = 0;
$whatever = "5865/100";

eval ('$answer = ' . $whatever . ';');
print($answer);
```

Comment: This will always create a syntax error as you forgot to add a ; after $whatever in the string that is eval'd